# Images in assets are not getting served in X-Accel on NGINX and Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, asset-pipeline

I've activated X-Accel with NGINX for my rails app. Now, I've got a curious problem.

My static images in /app/assets/images are not getting displayed anymore. The css and js stuff works but not the images.

The error is:

```
Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/var/www/cube/app/assets/images/cube_logo_3d.png"
```

Why does this happen? I have absolutely no clue and found nothing so far on google.

BTW: this happens on development mode.

Regards, Alex

Comment: Can you provide this app nginx related configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

if your assets are in `/app/assets/images` , then sprokets will copy them over to `/public/assets` 
The `/public` is supposed to be your web-servers document root. your static assets should be in  the document root (or its sub folders). Change your image path to this and try.